# Binary search warning in CFArrayBSearchValues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray, binary-search

i'm using `CFArrayBSearchValues`.

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001192-CH201-F10956

It works successfully but compiler show me a warning on first parameter:

```
CFIndex indexResult = CFArrayBSearchValues( 
                         m_Locations, 
                         CFRangeMake(0, [m_Locations count]), 
                         data, 
                         PGPlaceDataCompare, nil);
```

[image]

`CFArrayBSearch` expect as first parameter an `CFArrayRef`.
My `m_Locations` is an `NSMutableArray`.

How to resolve this warning? I need to do any cast to NSMutableArray to CFArrayRef?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just cast the NSMutableArray to CFArrayRef.

```
CFIndex indexResult = CFArrayBSearchValues( 
                         (CFArrayRef)m_Locations, 
                         CFRangeMake(0, [m_Locations count]), 
                         data, 
                         PGPlaceDataCompare, NULL);
```

---

On iOS 4.0 or later you could use the [Objective-C method `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3ainSortedRange%3aoptions%3ausingComparator%3a) instead.

```
 NSUInteger indexResult = [m_Locations
                            indexOfObject:data
                            inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [m_Locations count])
                                  options:0
                          usingComparator:^(id a, id b) { ... }];
```